# Change variable names into variable labels and remove legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggplotly

I created a function to produce ggplot choropleth maps, and it works :) However, I would like to remove the legend title (see picture below), since it now says 'I'. Furthermore, I would like to change the hover text into the variable labels as adapted in the Maps dataframe. However, when I merge this datafile with the shape file, en furthermore turn the MAPS dataframe into a readable format for ggplot, the variable labels are lost in the process. So, I would like to maintain the variable labels, and also want to incorporate the variable labels somehow in my function code, so I get the variable label of the fill= variable in my ggplotly hover text.

Below my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(cbsodataR)
library(plotly)
library(sjlabelled)
library(expss)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(rgdal)
library(plyr)

#Loading shapefile
ShapefileWijken <- readOGR("/Users/anne/Desktop/RondeVenen/ALGEMEEN_DATA/SHAPEFILES_DRV_6PC_5PC_Gemeente/WijkenEnBuurten/WijkenEnBuurten.shp")
#Opening data Dutch public database
Maps <- cbs_get_data("84583NED", 
                   select=c("AantalInwoners_5","HuishoudensTotaal_28", 
                              "Woningvoorraad_34", "GemiddeldInkomenPerInkomensontvanger_65", "Codering_3"))
#Merge data with shapefile
MAPS <- merge(ShapefileWijken, 
              Maps, 
              by.x = "BU_CODE", 
              by.y="Codering_3", 
              all=FALSE)
#Turn data into readable format for ggplot
MAPS@data$id <- rownames(MAPS@data)
TUSSEN <- fortify(MAPS, region="id")
CHOROPLETH <- merge(TUSSEN, MAPS@data, by="id")
library(plyr)
CHOROPLETH <- join(TUSSEN, MAPS@data, by="id")

###FUNCTION MAPS
ggplot_MAP <- function(i){
  ggplot(data = CHOROPLETH, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill=i), color="black")  +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="#99cc33", high="#009999") +
    theme_void() + 
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line.y=element_blank(), axis.line.x=element_blank(), 
          legend.title = element_blank())
}

#Adding gg plot choropleth map to shiny server 
output$MAPINWONERS <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot_MAP(CHOROPLETH$AantalInwoners_5)) %>% config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c(
      'sendDataToCloud', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d', 'toggleSpikelines',
      'hoverClosestCartesian', 'hoverCompareCartesian',
      'zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','zoomIn2d','zoomOut2d'
    ), displaylogo=FALSE) %>% layout(dragmode=FALSE)
```

[image: Example ggplot map]

Comment: It is difficult to help you without reproducible example. Could you provide sample of your `ShapefileWijken`. You can do it with `dput(ShapefileWijken)`.

Comment: Hi @GregoryDemin when I run: dput(ShapefileWijken) in R, the output is very very long. I can't put it in a comment nor am I able to put it in the main post. What best to do now?

Comment: Generally, `merge` between data.frames preserves labels. But `ShapefileWijken` is not data.frame. Is it possible to merge `Maps` at the last stage, to the `CHOROPLETH` data.frame?

Comment: Thanks Gregory, I will try to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove legend title by adding `labs(fill=NULL)` immediately after your `geom_polygon()` statement.  To get the desired hover text, define `text=paste("Text1",var1,"\nText2",var2)` inside the `aes` of `ggplot`; here Text1 and Text2 will be your desired text, and var1 and var2 will be your variable labels.  Then include `tooltip=c("text")` in `ggplotly`.